# Add centered box in html

Tags: html, css

I tried adding a centered box in html/css using a div and specifying a class for it. I then specified the height and width for the class and set the margin for 0 auto; however all I am getting is a white rectangle that spans the entire width of my page in the top, not a centered box. My css is:

```
    .rectangle {
    height: 700px;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rectangle is there and it's nicely centered.

You just need to make it visible. Giving a `background-color` should do the trick

```js
.rectangle {
  height: 700px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}
```

See [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/KqEEgj)

Comment: Thanks. That really helped! Do you have any idea why my background turns white when I put the box there?

Comment: @skyper No problem :) The default css background color is `transparent`. Unless you specify a color, it will default to `transparent` and therefore will not be visible - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Comment: So how would I change the background back to the image while keeping the box?

Comment: You could use `background-image` or `background` instead of `background-color`  - I updated the [Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/KqEEgj) with an image. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score -1):

The default background color is Transparent in html.Please check  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp)